# How to analyse packet infromation from a traffic dump file in C++?

Tags: c++, pcap, packet-capture

I write a *C* console program due to dump network traffic with "pCap" library. I want to get packet information (e.g. protocol-type, sender-ip, etc) from this binary file.

**My code :**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#ifndef WIN32
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#else
#include <winsock.h>
#endif 

#define LINE_LEN 16
void dispatcher_handler(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pcap_t *fp;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char source[PCAP_BUF_SIZE];

    if(argc != 2){

        printf("usage: %s filename", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create the source string according to the new WinPcap syntax */
    if(pcap_createsrcstr(source,         // variable that will keep the source string
        PCAP_SRC_FILE,  // we want to open a file
        NULL,           // remote host
        NULL,           // port on the remote host
        argv[1],        // name of the file we want to open
        errbuf          // error buffer
        ) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError creating a source string\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Open the capture file */
    if((fp = pcap_open(source,         // name of the device
        65536,          // portion of the packet to capture
        // 65536 guarantees that the whole packet will be captured on all the link layers
        PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS,     // promiscuous mode
        1000,              // read timeout
        NULL,              // authentication on the remote machine
        errbuf         // error buffer
        )) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUnable to open the file %s.\n", source);
        return -1;
    }

    // read and dispatch packets until EOF is reached
    pcap_loop(fp, 0, dispatcher_handler, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void dispatcher_handler(u_char *temp1,
    const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *pkt_data)
{
    u_int i = 0;
    /* print pkt timestamp and pkt len */
    printf("%ld:%ld (%ld)\n", header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec, header->len);

    /* Print the packet */
    for(i = 1; (i < header->caplen + 1); i++)
    {
        printf("%.2x ", pkt_data[i - 1]);
        if((i % LINE_LEN) == 0) printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

How can i read traffic information clearly (not hex codes) from traffic file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for inspecting traffic file, first we need to save it in hexadecimal file structure :

```
 printf("%.2x ", pkt_data[i - 1]);
```

after that we can analysis hexadecimal strings.
its work 100 percentage!